# Identify GPS data from GPS tracking system

Tags: tracking, gps

I have a GPS tracking system and I managed to get some data from it already, but I don't know what kind of data that is exactly; is anyone able to identify/recognize the following string and its meaning:

```
037.076.003.086.60125-079.172.241.067.00080: ##,imei:359710046026499,A;
```

- `079.172.241.067.00080`: I think this is the IP of my tracking system
- `##,imei:359710046026499,A`: This is the IMEI
- `037.076.003.086.60125`: What is this and how can I use it?

Comment: Might help if you gave some details about the GPS system in use. Clearly related to a mobile phone but we don't have much to go on.

Comment: I don't know any details about this. This is a noname GPS tracker...

Comment: The imei (International Mobile Equipment Identity) is a unique 15 digit identification number of your phone/modem: http://www.imei.info/?imei=359710046026499

Comment: @user1709024 What you think is an IP address, it doesn't look so to me. It would be also interesting to know what the final `A` and the double `#` mean, they're not actually part of the IMEI.